# iwconfig no wireless extentions

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox

I'm trying to learn about security and me and my father in law wanted to try our wifi's.

I'm running kali linux on VM Virtualbox based on windows 10. I have a Lenovo laptop with built in wifi (I am not using a USB).

I've been googling and youtubing for days now, but I can't make this work. When I type iwconfig in the terminal I only get the reply "no wireless extentions".

I do understand that the problem probably is in the Virtualbox, not detecting the wifi properly since I'm not using a USB.

Any solution to this or do I have to get a USB? Is there another way then iwconfig?

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: You won't be able to use built-in WiFi adapter as a WiFi adapter in virtual machine. Anyway it probably won't be possible to change it into monitor mode. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You mostly don't "connect to wifi" in a VM, since if you let the VM have direct access to the hardware ("passthrough") then your host will not be able to use it. And I have never seen any VM solution provides wifi emulation. Also, it's NOT like every (or any) VM solution has "all-round" passthrough capability that you can do that to any kind of hardware.

But yeah if you want to try out how wifi and so work in Linux (in a VM), getting an extra USB wifi adapter and dedicate it to the VM with USB passthrough available in VirtualBox can be an option.

P.S. You may want to pick carefully since wifi adapters aren't really well supported in Linux. Even if it has driver available as source code or binary blobs from the community or the vendor, you'll need to manage to build and install the kernel module properly to use the adapter. Not many of them (especially the USB ones / the recent "ac" ones) are supported by the upstream kernel out of the box (and even if it does the driver may not work really well).